# Why my result and weka result is different in attribute selection (using BestFirst)?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, feature-selection

I am trying to select attribute using weka libraries. I have written the following code. I am trying with spambase data set(from UCI).

```
BestFirst BS=new BestFirst();
CfsSubsetEval cf=new CfsSubsetEval();
cf.buildEvaluator(data);
int arr2[];
arr2=BS.search(cf, data);
```

After running this code I have found 10 attributes. 
But when I use the weka tool and select CCfsSubsetEval and BestFirst as search method, the weka tool selects 15 attributes.

what is the problem with my code ?

Comment: Both `BestFirst` and `CfsSubsetEval` have several parameters. Are the defaults the same for the Java libraries and the tool?